# Call a function using expansion pack on a same function

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I would like to be able to call a function over any number of arguments, with each argument's value supplied by another function:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class MyClass
{
public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        doSomethingProxy(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
    }

private:
    template <std::size_t... I>
    void doSomethingProxy(std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        m_obj.doSomething({get()...}); // T::doSomething() expects an object whose constructor has N number of arguments, and I would like to call the get() function for each argument of said constructor, N times
    }
    
    int get() { return 0; }

    T m_obj{};
};
```

However doing the above results in the error

```
error: expansion pattern get() contains no parameter packs
```

I think the issue is that `get()...` does not depend on `I`, but I'm not sure how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(I,get())` is using the parameter pack and results in `get()` (comma operator, evaluates both operands, returns the rhs). To silence a warning about no effect of lhs of comma operator you might need to write `((void)I,get())`:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
class MyClass
{
public:
    void doSomething()
    {
        doSomethingProxy(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
    }

private:
    template <std::size_t... I>
    void doSomethingProxy(std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        m_obj.doSomething({ ((void)I,get())... }); 
    }
    
    int get() { return 0; }

    T m_obj{};
};
```

Comment: I had `error: left operand of comma operator has no effect` but changing the `I, get()` to `(void)I, get()` resolved it...
Also, where is the official documentation for this? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @zhanginou it's just the comma operator. It expand to `doSomething({ (0,get()), (1,get()), (2,get()), /*and more*/});`

Comment: @zhanginou if you want the standard, I think they are at [§temp.variadic](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/temp.variadic#5) and [§expr.comma](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.comma)

Comment: @zhanginou that should be a warning not an error. `I` having "no effect" is just what we want. I added the `(void)` to the answer